# How to print text with the value of a variable

Tags: python, printing

I have written a small function to check which of two values is closest to zero. The issue I am having is with the print statement at the end: I want it  to print the text followed by whichever value it determines is the closest.

```
def closestcheck(ylow, yhigh, ylist, xlist):
    ynew = (ylow + yhigh) / 2
    #The following 2 prints are purely to check the calculations are correct
    print(ynew)
    print(ylow,yhigh)
    if ynew > 0:
        print('The closest value of theta is' % ylow)
    else:
        print('The closest value of theta is' % yhigh)

closestcheck(y0[-1],y0[-2],y0,x0)
```

It will print the text but not the number

> 6.13910823576e-07
>
> -3.46867223283e-06 4.69649387998e-06
>
> The closest value of theta is

This specific syntax has worked in other cases but not here, I'm unsure as to why. An explanation of why this isn't working and how to fix it would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use string templating, but you didn't specify where in the template to fill in the variable.

```
if ynew>0:
    print('The closest value of theta is %f' % ylow)
else:
    print('The closest value of theta is %f' % yhigh)
```

While you're at it, string templating with `%` kind of smells like grandma's linen cupboard these days.  Recommended to use this instead:

```
y_closest = ylow if ynew > 0 else yhigh
print('The closest value of theta is {y}'.format(y=y_closest))
```

Comment: Right thank you! That works perfectly now. So the %f is a marker and will put the float of whatever follows the % after the ' mark?

Comment: Have a read of this for more info on string formatting - https://pyformat.info/. `%f` prints the value as a floating point number. You would use `%s` if you want to print a string.